# Paypal does not return the actual total amount

Tags: jsp, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment

I am using paypal as a payment gateway .I added items to my shopping cart it shows correct information but the total amount is showing not the actual total amount.Anyone can find error in my code ?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<form name="paypalForm" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sumn2u@gmail.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
 <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Ice Age ">
 <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="2">
 <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="23.95">
 <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="1.75">
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost:8084/DVDAppp/return.jsp?success=true">
 <input name="notify_url" value="http://localhost:8084/DVDAppp/test.jsp" type="hidden">
 <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://localhost:8084/WebEE/index.jsp">
 <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but6.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it" s="" fast,="" free="" and="" secure!'="">
</form>
```

Comment: The text in the image is tiny but it looks right to me. What are you saying is wrong?

Comment: well i figure out what the mistake that i have i made i was not multiply the quantity with the price in item so it cause me problem. another thing did i need a actual url for Instant Notification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total amount is correct in this code. As for the 'notify_url' part, if you do not use PayPal IPN function in your Live model and just for the testing purpose, you are able to put any of your preferred URL for Instant Notification. For the more information about PayPal IPN, you can refer to the link below.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/